# Magento Help - Left Bar has shifting down and unclickable

Tags: css, magento, navigation

I am not that great at programming, I just look after basic updates and such for my website Heritage Hockey.

I'm not sure how it happened but the whole left bar (including navigation) has shifted down under 'On Sale' items and I am unsure how to fix it. The links are not clickable anymore either. You can see my issue [here](http://www.heritagehockey.com/index.php/).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

give your `<div class="main">` a `float` value of `right`, like so:

```
.main {
  float: right
}
```

links are not clickable because the footer's div appears on top of them, clear the float with the following:

```
.footer {
  clear: both
}
```

and your layout should be fine again

Comment: Where would I add that? Within Magento (if so where) or would that have to go in the HTML code?

Comment: well you should modify the main .css file of your Magento theme, do you know where it is and how to access it? otherwise you could put those declarations inside a `<style>` tag within your `<head>` but that's not that elegant

Comment: usually the main css file of a Magento theme is in, for example, `/skin/frontend/entreprise/default/css` folder